# what is the easiest and most straightforward way to set up a new syncronized vs solution in vsts?

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio, azure-devops

What is the easiest and most straightforward way to set up a new syncronized solution in VSTS?  It feels like I tend to use a variety of different approaches when I do this but if you were starting from scratch then what steps would you choose to take as the easiest and most straightforward approach?

It seems like I should be able to create a new solution in VS2017 and then righ-click it and select a context menu option like "Create New Repo > https:\mycorp.visualstudio.com\MyNewRepo"

However, I'm not sure if this option exists.  I haven't been able to find it off-hand in any case, although the latest MSFT UX isn't all that intuitive so maybe I'm just missing it.

Comment: Due to 9 views and no comments after an hour it appears that an easy and straightforward way to do this isn't common knowledge.  And what I'm describing seems like the most basic use case lol

Comment: What do you mean by a "synchronized solution"?

Comment: There usually has two ways to sync a solution with VSTS git repo: 1. create a solution firstly and then create a VSTS git repo in VS (as you mentioned); 2. create a VSTS git repo in VSTS web page, then clone the existing git repo in VS. Both of the ways are straightforward. And it's hard to say which one is easier, since different users prefer different ways.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t such option like Create new repo to create a new repository. You must create a new repository in VSTS.

So the easier way is connecting and clone the repository in VS, then create a new solution.